# Using functions as applicative functors/cartesians

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm using the `cats` lib for this.

It's easy enough to combine two lists using their applicative functor instance (or `Cartesian`, to be precise):

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

(List(23, 4), List(55, 56)).mapN(_ + _)
>> List(78, 79, 59, 60)
```

However, I can't seem to be able to do the same with two functions:

```
val strLength: String => Int = _.length

(strLength, strLength).mapN(_ + _)
>> value mapN is not a member of (String => Int, String => Int)
```

It does work if I do some of the implicit conversions explicitly, and if I create a type alias to give the compiler a hand:

```
type F[A] = Function1[String, A]
val doubleStrLength = catsSyntaxTuple2Cartesian[F, Int, Int]((strLength, strLength)).mapN(_ + _)

doubleStrLength("hello")
>> 10
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Seems excessively verbose

Edit: I create a worksheet here if you wanna play with it: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dcastro/QhnD8gwEQEyfnr14g34d9g/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only works if you have `partial-unification` enabled. 
The easiest way to do so, is to add the `sbt-partial-unification` [plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification).

If you're on Scala 2.11.9 or newer, you can also simply add the compiler flag:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

Comment: Ah that's it! I remember hearing about Miles working on this a while ago. I guess I'm just too used to haskell now. Thanks!