# Using an Applicative Functor Functions with Cats and Scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats

How can I implement a similar Haskell function in Scala 3 and Cats?

```
ghci> (+) <$> (+1) <*> (+1) $ 10
22
```

There was a solution using `mapN`. It is mentioned here, [Using functions as applicative functors/cartesians](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562842/using-functions-as-applicative-functors-cartesians),  but I want a solution using `<*>` instead of `mapN`. I tried something similar but it won't compile

```
  import cats._
  import cats.implicits._

  type Func1[Y] = Int => Y

  val add1: Func1[Int] = (x: Int) => x + 1
  val addXY: Func1[Func1[Int]] = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x + y

  val foo: Func1[Func1[Func1[Int]]] = Applicative[Func1].pure(addXY)
  val bar: Func1[Func1[Int]] = Applicative[Func1].pure(add1)
  val foobar = foo <*> bar 
  foobar(10)  // should be 22 but it can't compile
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you even trying to do? I have spent 10 minutes trying to make sense of all that. Note that I have used and contributed to **cats** for the last five years. - Anyways, please, don't write code like this ever. This is the kind of code why folks then go a write reddit posts about why **Scala** is academic language that nobody sues for real.

Comment: My goal is to implement something similar to the Haskell example. Is that possible? The "kinda code" you are referring to is my play code. It could be wrong altogether. I attempt to get to something similar to the Haskell example

Comment: I'm really failing to stretch my imagination and get 22 out of that example. Can you explain how you're getting that number? 21 I can reproduce in Haskell, but I really don't see how you're finding 22.

Comment: I mean if your goal is just compose a list of functions into a big one, no need to do all this trickery, just use `andThen` - That is what my limited experience with **Haskell** tells me the code is doing.

Comment: Edited the Haskell example to reflect the actual. My Scala implementation could be wrong or buggy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala Cats admits functions as `Applicative` instances, just like Haskell does. The Haskell code you wrote is

```
(+) <$> (+1) <*> (+1) $ 10
```

We can write these functions in Scala as

```
def add1(x: Int) = x + 1

def addXY(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
```

Now `<*>` works like it does in Haskell, but `<$>` doesn't exist as infix (not least of all because `$` isn't a symbol character in JVM-based languages). Remember that `f <$> x` is just equivalent to `fmap f x`, or (by the `Applicative` laws) `pure f <*> x`.

So we can write

```
val foobar = addXY.pure[[X] =>> Function1[Int, X]] <*> add1 <*> add1
println(foobar(10))
```

Now, while Cats doesn't provide an infix `<$>` that I know of, we can easily write one ourselves as an extension method. We can't name it `<$>` because the dollar sign is funny on the JVM, but we can write `<@>` instead.

```
extension[A, B](left: A => B)
  def <@>[F[_]: Functor](right: F[A]): F[B] =
    right.fmap(left)
```

Now we can say

```
val foobar = addXY <@> add1 <*> add1
println(foobar(10))
```

**Complete example:**

```
package example

import cats.*
import cats.implicits.*

def add1(x: Int) = x + 1

def addXY(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y

extension[A, B](left: A => B)
  def <@>[F[_]: Functor](right: F[A]): F[B] =
    right.fmap(left)

@main def main(args: String*): Unit = {
  val foobar = addXY <@> add1 <*> add1
  println(foobar(10))
}
```

---

## Scala 2

All of the above is written in Scala 3. If you're in Scala 2, then you have to do a bit of messy business to get Scala to treat the functions the way you want. As you've already seen, you have to write a `type` alias to get the right type-level generic behavior (if you want to call `pure`, for instance). The `def` functions have to be explicitly converted to functions with a suffix `_`. And the `extension` method will need to be an old-school `implicit class`.

So all in all, this is the same program written in Scala 2.

```
package example

import cats._
import cats.implicits._

import scala.language.higherKinds

object Main {

  implicit class FmapExtension[A, B](
    val left: A => B,
  ) extends AnyVal {

    def <@>[F[_]: Functor](right: F[A]): F[B] =
      right.fmap(left)

  }

  def add1(x: Int) = x + 1

  def addXY(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val foobar = (addXY _) <@> (add1 _) <*> (add1 _)
    println(foobar(10))
  }

}
```

Comment: I really fail to see why anyone would want to write code like this but meh, have an upvote for the hard work :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I agree that it's not very idiomatic Scala in production, but Scala can be a very fun language for academic use as well, and the fact that the tooling can be stretched this far to look, basically, like Haskell, is fascinating in itself. I would never write this in a real project, but I would 100% write this for a coding challenge or for fun.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. As he said, it is unlikely this code will go into production. This is especially true if the team members are Java developers working on Scala code. I am curious and want to learn more about Cats. Thanks